# Running Arduino command on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspbian, python

I am a mechanical engineering student who is currently doing my final year project.

Basically I am trying to develop coding for the cornering movement for in pipe robots, but my problem now is that I am not familiar with Raspberry Pi 3.

I have the coding which is already run on Arduino, so I want to ask whether there's a way that I can convert the command from Arduino  to Python so that it can be run in Raspberry Pi?

Comment: There was a similar question recently.  The short answer is no.

Comment: @joan your short answer makes it sound like that `RasPiArduino` stuff basically doesn't work. Is that the case?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I have no idea what RasPiArduino does.  It would be pretty impressive if it could convert an arbitrary Arduino sketch to Python and make it work on the Pi.  It would fail immediately if the sketch used analog inputs.

Comment: @joan Well, that's more or less what their [readme](https://github.com/me-no-dev/RasPiArduino) file says. Sure, there's no analog inputs, and I wouldn't expect the timing to be as precise as it is on a real microcontroller, but still.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev It only mentions pinMode/digitalRead/digitalWrite/analogWrite.  Arduino has tons of libraries and many more functions.

Comment: @joan It sure has basic functions like `delay()` and the like. How many libraries are supported is another question.

Comment: Lots on Google about RasPiArduino, but just take a quick look at http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html and it will be immediately obvious that you are better off utilizing @joan's pigpio library so you can go native in Python with confidence.